# Extract date from a string and copy it to other date column SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, date

I have a SQL table with few fields.

id, Date, Description, etc

The description is a string where people add some content..

Example 1: `Pista Automobilistica Con Automobili 500 04/07/1957 , Poi Le 500`

Example 2: `Context date: 09/02/1979.. text text..`

I need to extract the date (`d/m/y`) from the text and copy it to de Date column in sql format (`y/m/d`)

Comment: which dbms are you using? Oracle, SQL Server, MySQL, Postgres etc.

Comment: A table has _columns_, not fields.

Comment: I'm using Mysql.

Comment: Better than using date as a string is to use date data type, which means final format is dependent of MySQL server settings.

Comment: What if the string has multiple dates (or strings that look like dates)?

Comment: it may contain (month/Year) but it seems it contains only one date for each string..

Comment: You can use a regular expression. See this post for more details:
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/34724/how-to-use-substring-using-regexp-in-mysql - 
However - it would be preferable to extract it before entering it into the db in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

-- This query return the date of the column descrip (only one date by string)

select str_to_date(substr(descrip,instr(descrip,'/')-2,10),'%d/%m/%Y') as fecha from tabla;

Answer (score 0):

```
--This is for MSSQL Server, I hope you got the idea

declare @str1 varchar(max),@str2 varchar(max),@str3 varchar(max)

 set @str1='Pista Automobilistica Con Automobili 500 04/07/1957 , Poi Le 500'
 set @str2='Context date: 09/02/1979.. text text..'
 set @str3='xzczxczxczxcxzc 12/12/2018 xcvxcvxc'

 print convert(date,substring(@str1,CHARINDEX('/',@str1,1)-2,10),101)
 print convert(date,substring(@str2,CHARINDEX('/',@str2,1)-2,10),101)
 print convert(date,substring(@str3,CHARINDEX('/',@str3,1)-2,10),101)
```